# Using SynchronizationContext with TrackingParticipant

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, workflow-foundation-4, s#arp-architecture

I have a custom Tracking Participant:

```
public class ErsTrackingParticipant : TrackingParticipant, IErsTrackingParticipant
{
    private readonly INHibernateRepository<ErsTrackingRecord> _ersTrackingRecordRepository;

    public ErsTrackingParticipant(INHibernateRepository<ErsTrackingRecord> ersTrackingRecordRepository)
    {
        this._ersTrackingRecordRepository = ersTrackingRecordRepository;
    }

    protected override void Track(TrackingRecord record, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        ErsTrackingRecord ersTrackingRecord = TrackingCommand.GetTrackingRecord(record);
        this._ersTrackingRecordRepository.Save(ersTrackingRecord);
    }
}

public interface IErsTrackingParticipant
{
}
```

and a Workflow Host Helper:

```
public class WorkflowHostHelper: IWorkflowHostHelper
{
    private WorkflowApplication _workflowApplication;
    AutoResetEvent _instanceUnloaded = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    private IErsTrackingParticipant _ersTrackingParticipant;

    private bool _isCompleted = false;

    public string InstanceStoreConnectionString { get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InstanceStoreConnectionString"]; } }

    public WorkflowHostHelper(IErsTrackingParticipant ersTrackingParticipant)
    {
        _ersTrackingParticipant = ersTrackingParticipant;
    }

    public void Initialize(Activity workflowType)
    {
        _workflowApplication = new WorkflowApplication(workflowType);
        TrackingProfile trackingProfile = new TrackingProfile() { Name = "TroubleshootingProfile", ActivityDefinitionId = "*" };
        trackingProfile.Queries.Add(new WorkflowInstanceQuery { States = { "*" } });
        trackingProfile.Queries.Add(new ActivityStateQuery { States = { "*" } });
        trackingProfile.Queries.Add(new ActivityScheduledQuery());
        trackingProfile.Queries.Add(new BookmarkResumptionQuery() { Name = "*" });

        _workflowApplication.Extensions.Add(_ersTrackingParticipant);

        SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        _workflowApplication.SynchronizationContext = synchronizationContext;
        _workflowApplication.InstanceStore = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStore(InstanceStoreConnectionString);

        _workflowApplication.PersistableIdle = (e) =>
            { return PersistableIdleAction.Persist; };
        _workflowApplication.Completed = (e) =>
            {
                _isCompleted = true;
                _instanceUnloaded.Set();
            };
        _workflowApplication.Idle = (e) =>
            { _instanceUnloaded.Set(); };

    } //Rest ommiitted...
```

When the repository trys to save back to the database it errors:

```
'((SharpArch.NHibernate.NHibernateRepositoryWithTypedId<EmployeeRequestSystem.Domain.ErsTrackingRecord,int>)(this._ersTrackingRecordRepository)).Session' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

SharpArch.NHibernate.Contracts.Repositories.INHibernateRepositoryWithTypedId<T,TId>.DbContext = {SharpArch.NHibernate.DbContext}
```

In workflow activities I can reference the context and use service locators such as:

```
    protected override void CacheMetadata(CodeActivityMetadata metadata)
    {
        base.CacheMetadata(metadata);
        metadata.AddDefaultExtensionProvider<INHibernateRepository<AuthorisationRequest>>(
            () => new NHibernateRepository<AuthorisationRequest>());
    }
```

...

```
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        var authorisationRequestRepoistory = context.GetExtension<INHibernateRepository<AuthorisationRequest>>();
```

How can I get the correct context through to my ErsTrackingParticipant?

Answer (score 1):

From your question it's not clear to me what the SynchronizationContext has to do with the null reference.  It would help if you can track down exactly what was null.

The SynchronizationContext.Current property will in most cases be null.  It will have a value only when setup by something in the hosting environment.  I would not set the WorkflowApplication.Synchronization context property unless I found that SynchronizationContext.Current had a value.

I don't understand why you want a "context" in the tracking participant.  What "context" are you referring to?  SynchronizationContext?  CodeActivityContext?

Comment: I found to allow the nhibernate session (in a Castle Windsor container) to be used within the workflows I had to share the MVC context with the workflow. I thought that the null reference was pointing towards the lack of Session available within the context (or thread?) that the tracking participant runs in. Will I have to leave my DI behind and set a separate session for my tracking participant?

Comment: Context is typically shared per-thread.  To pass a context to an activity you could pass it as an extension.

Comment: I set the SynchronizationContext of the workflow to be the current context of the MVC application to allow me to share the session. This works fine although I'd be interested in seeing what you mean about passing as an extension. I've done more research and it seems the TrackingParticipant always runs on it's own thread so it may not be possible to share the context.

Comment: When you create your tracking participant, can you pass into the ctor what you need?  You are right, you won't get it from the thread context in a tracking participant.